# How to find the vertices with integral coordinates of a triangle knowing that center and inradius?

Tags: geometry

I want to find the length of the sides of a triangle (not right triangle) with center $C(1; 2)$ and inradius $R=5$. How can I do?
I tried.

- Write the equation of the circle with center $C(1; 2)$ and inradius $R=5$;
- Choose three points $A(-3,-1)$, $B(4,6), $C(5,5) lies on circle;
- Write the equation of the tangents at the point $A$, $B$, $C$;
- This tangents cut at three points $M$, $N$, $P$. 
  A problem is opened, how to find the vertices with integral coordinates?

Comment: Surely you meant "...of a triangle with **incircle's center** C..."

Comment: (3,6)is not a point on the circle. Can you re-read your question and clarify?

Comment: Why did you choose the points on the circle that you did? Is that given?

Comment: Are the points $A,B,C$ where the circle is tangent to the sides of the triangle required to have integer coordinates? Or are you trying to pick $A,B,C$ in such a way that the triangle $M,N,P$ formed by intersecting the three tangents has each of $M,N,P$ with integer coordinates? [I don't think it would be possible that all of $A,B,C,M,N,P$ have integer coordinates.]

Comment: @coffeemath: There are ways for all six points to be at integer coordinates. Example: $$A=(-2,6),B=(1,-3),C=(5,5)\quad M=(-14,-3),N=(2,9),P=(11,-3)$$ I guess it's only possible if one of the tangetnts is horizontal or vertical, though.

Comment: @MvG A nice case of all integer coordinates. However the large triangle $MNP$ has a 90 deg. angle at $N$, and OP was looking for a non-right triangle.

Comment: @coffeemath: You are right, I missed that parenthesis in the question. Then I agree with you: there seem to be no non-right triangles with integral touching points as well as integral corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this question easier, I'll put the center of the incircle in the origin. Any integral solution can be easily transferred to the location you indicated. Let $M,N,P$ be the corners of the triangle, as used in your question. Let the coordinates of $M$ be $(M_x,M_y)\in\mathbb Z^2$. One important quantity in your scenario is

$$d:=M_x^2+M_y^2-25$$

As you can see, as long as $M$ is outside the circle, that quantity will be positive. Its square root can be used to describe the tangents from $M$ to the circle:

\begin{align*}
t_1 &= \left\{(x,y)\;\middle\vert\;
(5M_x+\sqrt dM_y)x + (5M_y-\sqrt dM_x)y = 5\left(M_x^2+M_y^2\right) \right\} \\
t_2 &= \left\{(x,y)\;\middle\vert\;
(5M_x-\sqrt dM_y)x + (5M_y+\sqrt dM_x)y = 5\left(M_x^2+M_y^2\right) \right\}
\end{align*}

The way I obtained these tangents is by performing the dual of a conic-line intersection, as described in section 11.3 of [*Perspectives on Projective Geometry*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642172857) by Richter-Gebert.

If these tangents are to cross any points with integer coordinates, their slopes have to be rational (or $\infty$ for vertical lines). These slopes are

$$-\frac{5M_x\pm\sqrt dM_y}{5M_y\mp\sqrt dM_x}$$

There are two conceivable ways these slopes might be rational: either because $\sqrt d$ is rational, or because numerator and denominator are rational multiples of the same irrational number. If one treats $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ as a two-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vectorspace, then this translates into the requirement that the two vectors have to be linearily dependent, which here means

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
5M_x & \pm M_y \\
5M_y & \mp M_x
\end{pmatrix}=\mp5\left(M_x^2+M_y^2\right)=0$$

So the only other way would mean $M$ is the origin, which is of course impossible. So we are left with the requirement that $\sqrt d$ be rational, so $d$ must be a square number.

Now one possible way to tackle this problem is iterating over all integral coordinates in a given range, and checking whether the resulting $d$ is square. One can build up a collection of possible corner points, and using the coordinates of the tangents, one can see which corners could belong to the same triangle. The $t_1$ of one point must match the $t_2$ of the other edge, but scalar multiples of the coefficients describe the same line. I've [implemented such an enumeration](http://ideone.com/A7m1y7). Many results contain $5$ as one of the coordinates of one of the points. But not all do, so one of the more interesting results is

\begin{align*}
M&=(-11, -2) & N&=(  1,  7) & P&=( 13, -9)
\end{align*}

After moving $C$ back to where you defined it, this becomes

\begin{align*}
M&=(-10, 0) & N&=(  2,  9) & P&=( 14, -7)
\end{align*}

[image: Illustration of one possible right-angled solution]

However, the solution above has aright angle at $N$, so as your question asks for a slution without a right angle, this one is not acceptable. Thanks to @coffeemath for making me aware of this condition. It seems that at least if the absolute value of the coordinates is restricted to no more than $1000$, then all solution without a right angle neccessarily have either a horizontal or a vertical tangent. So here is another go, again first in the untranslated situation:

\begin{align*}
M&=(-11, -10) & N&=( -3,  5) & P&=( 25, 5)
\end{align*}

After moving $C$ back to where you defined it, this becomes

\begin{align*}
M&=(-10, -8) & N&=(  -2,  7) & P&=( 26, 7)
\end{align*}

[image: Illustration of solution without right angle]

I also [adapted my program](http://ideone.com/xJQ62j) to filter out the right-angled triangles automatically. There are still many possible solutions remaining, but none with all coordinates less than $25$ in absolute value, in the coordinate system where the circle center is the origin.

Comment: What the program which I run your code? Can you write in Maple program?

Comment: @minthao_2011: I don't understand the first part of your comment. As for Maple: given enough experience, one could certainly also write this in Maple, but personally I've never implemented much in terms of data structures in that language, so writing this in Maple is more work than I want to put into this.

Comment: This triangle $MNP$ has a right angle at $N$. (OP wanted a non-right triangle example.) Did your program find any non-right triangle examples?

Comment: @coffeemath: I just realized that this right-angle restriction applies to my solution as well. Updated my answer: there are indeed valid solutions, but you can't avoid horizontal or vertical tangents in that case.

Comment: The nonright triangle example is also nice in that its sides are integers $28,17,39.$ (I would +1 for the answer, and this added example, but I already upped before...)

Comment: @MvG How can I run your code?

Comment: @minthao_2011: That code is written in C++, so you'd install a C++ compiler recent enough to understand the C++11 dialect, and compile it to obtain an executable you can run from the command line of your operating system. Or you stick to ideone and run your code online. As you can see by following the links, my code was run there, and its output is already visible.

Comment: @MvG Thank you very much.

Comment: I copy your code and tried run. How can I delete the number in front of each line?

Comment: @minthao_2011: ideone has a button to copy the code, without line numbers. It also has a button to fork an existing post, so that you can modify it to your liking. I'm not going to answer more details on how to use ideone, or on how to compile C++ code. This is not the forum for such tutorials.

Comment: @MvG Thank you very much. Now, I can do it.

Comment: @MvG Can you write a program that find the interger vertices of a triangle knowing that its sides? For example, the triagle with sides 17, 28, 39.

Comment: @MvG I can do it.

Comment: @MvG Can you write a program for problem "A sphere is inscribed in a  tetrahedron with coordinates centre and vetices of sphere are also triples of integers"? For example Tetrahedron with vertices A(1,2,3), B(-2, 8, 9) , C(5, 0, 7) and D(3, 4, 2) has centre of sphere is inscribed I(2, 3, 4) and radius is r = 1.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I won't write a 3d version of the code in a comment here, not do I have time to look at that any time soon. Feel free to post a separate question for that, citing the one here, and paste the link to that question in a comment here.

Comment: @MvG I posted a new question at here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067098/a-sphere-is-inscribed-in-a-tetrahedron-with-coordinates-centre-and-vetices-of-sp